# javascript textbox validation

Tags: javascript

i have a textbox in a jsp page

```
<td><label for="customer.fcDate" class="desc"><bean:message key="label.customer.fcDate" /></label></td>
            <td>
                <table><tbody><tr>
                        <td><input type="Text" name="customer.fcDate" id="customer.fcDate" style="customer.fcDate" class="SingleLineTextField" maxlength="10" size="15" tabindex="1" ></td>
                <td><a href="javascript:NewCal('customer.fcDate','mmddyyyy')"><img align="middle" src="Images/cal.jpg" width="20" height="20" border="0" alt="Pick a date"></a></td>

                </tr></tbody></table>
            </td>
```

now i want to check that the box must not be null using javascript. how to do it?

can you explain it little more?

```
     <td> <table>
 <tbody><tr> 
<td>
<input type="Text" name="customer.fcDate" id="customer.fcDate" style="customer.fcDate" class="SingleLineTextField" maxlength="10" size="15" tabindex="1" onblur="nullcheck()">
</td> 
<td><a href="javascript:NewCal('customer.fcDate','mmddyyyy')">
<img align="middle" src="Images/cal.jpg" width="20" height="20" border="0" alt="Pick a date"></a></td> </tr></tbody></table> </td>
```

in this way?????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just call this function on Blur to event to check text box is empty or having value.

```
  function nullcheck()
  {
    if(document.getElementById(fcDate).value=="")
    {
      alert("Please enter value.");
      return false;
    }
  }
```

`onblur="nullcheck()"` -- add this to text box property.

Comment: can you explain it little more?

<td>
 <table>
<tbody><tr>
       <td><input type="Text" name="customer.fcDate" id="customer.fcDate" style="customer.fcDate" class="SingleLineTextField" maxlength="10" size="15" tabindex="1" onblur="nullcheck()"></td>
    <td><a href="javascript:NewCal('customer.fcDate','mmddyyyy')"><img align="middle" src="Images/cal.jpg" width="20" height="20" border="0" alt="Pick a date"></a></td>
    
    </tr></tbody></table>
   </td>

in this way?????

Comment: On the above "input type="Text" name="customer.fcDate", you need to integrate this function. ???

Answer (score 2):

```
if (document.getElementById("customer.fcDate").value == "") {
   // BAD!
} else {
   // GOOD!
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want an easy way, try using jquery validations.

here is a good one: http://demos.usejquery.com/ketchup-plugin/validation.html

if you just need plain js, just check if the input box value has a length of > 1

Answer (score 1):

In your validation function you will use something like:

```
var fcDateInput = document.getElementById('customer.fcDate');
if (fcDateInput == null || fcDateInput.value.length < 1) {
  alert("You should select a valid date");
} else {
  // everything goes right...
}
```